# Pyspark: TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable --- Using Window Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark

## #Trying to use Window Functions in PySpark

`from pyspark.sql import Row, functions as F`
`from pyspark.sql.functions import col, row_number`
`from pyspark.sql.window import Window`
`from pyspark.sql import SparkSession`

`Join_transaciones3_df = Join_transaciones3_df.withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().OVER(Window.partitionBy("Clave").orderBy(col("transaction_date"))))`

### Getting this error --> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap the `transaction_date` in the `col` method - try this:

```py
Join_transaciones3_df = Join_transaciones3_df.withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("Clave").orderBy("transaction_date")))
```